# How to filter numpy array by list of indices?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, nearest-neighbor

I have a numpy array, `filtered__rows`, comprised of LAS data `[x, y, z, intensity, classification]`.  I have created a `cKDTree` of points and have found nearest neighbors, `query_ball_point`, which is a list of indices for the point and its neighbors.

Is there a way to filter `filtered__rows` to create an array of only points whose index is in the list returned by `query_ball_point`?

Answer (score 106, accepted):

It looks like you just need a basic [integer array indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html#purely-integer-array-indexing):

```
filter_indices = [1,3,5]
np.array([11,13,155,22,0xff,32,56,88])[filter_indices]
```

Comment: Do you know how that translates for multi-dimensional arrays?

Comment: I answered the multi-dimm version, but don't mind if someone merges it with this answer.

Comment: fyi this has replacement aka the array being accessed does not shrink each time an index is accessed

Answer (score 68):

[`numpy.take`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.take.html) can be useful and works well for multimensional arrays.

```py
import numpy as np

filter_indices = [1, 2]
array = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 
                  [10, 20, 30, 40, 50], 
                  [100, 200, 300, 400, 500]])

axis = 0
print(np.take(array, filter_indices, axis))
# [[ 10  20  30  40  50]
#  [100 200 300 400 500]]

axis = 1
print(np.take(array, filter_indices, axis))
# [[  2   3]
#  [ 20  30]
# [200 300]]
```

Answer (score 19):

Using Docs: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.indexing.html
The following implementation should work for arbitrary number of dimensions/shapes for some numpy ndarray.

First we need a multi-dimensional set of indexes and some example data:

```
import numpy as np
y = np.arange(35).reshape(5,7)
print(y) 
indexlist = [[0,1], [0,2], [3,3]]
print ('indexlist:', indexlist)
```

To actually extract the intuitive result the trick is to use a Transpose:

```
indexlisttranspose = np.array(indexlist).T.tolist()
print ('indexlist.T:', indexlisttranspose)
print ('y[indexlist.T]:', y[ tuple(indexlisttranspose) ])
```

Makes the following terminal output:

> ```
> y: [[ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6]
>  [ 7  8  9 10 11 12 13]
>  [14 15 16 17 18 19 20]
>  [21 22 23 24 25 26 27]
>  [28 29 30 31 32 33 34]]
> indexlist: [[0, 1], [0, 2], [3, 3]]
> indexlist.T: [[0, 0, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
> y[indexlist.T]: [ 1  2 24]
> ```

The tuple... fixes a future warning which we can cause like so:

```
print ('y[indexlist.T]:', y[ indexlisttranspose ])
```

> ```
> FutureWarning: Using a non-tuple sequence for multidimensional indexing is deprecated; use `arr[tuple(seq)]` instead of `arr[seq]`.
> In the future this will be interpreted as an array index,
> `arr[np.array(seq)]`, which will result either in an error or a
> different result.
>     print ('y[indexlist.T]:', y[ indexlisttranspose ])
> y[indexlist.T]: [ 1  2 24]
> ```

Answer (score 12):

> Do you know how that translates for multi-dimensional arrays?

It can be expanded to multi dimensional arrays by giving a 1d array for every index so for a 2d array

```
filter_indices=np.array([[1,0],[0,1]])
array=np.array([[0,1],[1,2]])
print(array[filter_indices[:,0],filter_indices[:,1]])
```

will give you :
`[1,1]`

Scipy has an explanation on what will happen if you call:
`print(array[filter_indices])`

> Docs - https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.indexing.html

Comment: I assume this is faster than the other two answers with tuple conversions.

Answer (score 2):

The fastest way to do this is `X[tuple(index.T)]`, where `X` is the ndarray with the elements and `index` is the ndarray of indices wished to be retrieved.

Comment: Very quick for large arrays.  Thanks!

Comment: `X[tuple(index), :]` if X is 2 dimensional.