# Printing specific rows of an array in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, numpy

I am trying specific rows of the array `A` based on the list `J`. For instance, it should print 1st and 4th rows of `A` since `J=[[1,4]]` and append as shown in the expected output. I also present the current output.

```
import numpy as np

A=np.array([[1,2,3,4,5],
            [6,7,8,9,10],
            [11,12,13,14,15],
            [16,17,18,19,20],
            [21,22,23,24,25]])


J=[[1, 4]]

for i in J[0]:
     A=A[i]
     print([A])
```

The current output is

```
[array([ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10])]
[array(10)]
```

The expected output is

```
[array([[ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10],
        [21,22,23,24,25]])]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can do in one line:

```
np.array([list(A[i]) for i in J[0]])

#output
array([[ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10],
       [21, 22, 23, 24, 25]])
```

if you want to append to a list then:

```
l=[]
l.append(np.array([list(A[i]) for i in J[0]]))

#output
[array([[ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10],
       [21, 22, 23, 24, 25]])]
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you are re-writing your A array within your loop with `A=A[i]`, so when the code tries to find A[i] the second time, it will be filtering on the new A which is the row from the previous loop (hence the output of 10).  Pick a different letter to use here like this:

```
for i in J[0]:
    B = A[i]
    print([B])
```

Output:

```
[array([ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10])]
[array([21, 22, 23, 24, 25])]
```

To get your exact output of a list containing an array containing nested lists, you can create an empty list C, and add the list of B each loop then turn that into an array in a list at the end rather than printing each step, like this:

```
C = []
for i in J[0]:
    B=A[i]
    C += [list(B)]
C = [np.array(C)]
```

Now C is:

```
[array([[ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10],
       [21, 22, 23, 24, 25]])]
```

Comment: desired output is `[array([[ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10],[21,22,23,24,25]])]`

Comment: @YashMehta have added a second section

Comment: now it is perfect..!

Answer (score 0):

Define an empty array variable and append desired raw arrays inside the loop and after finishing print out this array.

```
B = []
for i in J[0]:
    B.append(A[i])
print([B])
```

O/P will be:

```
[[array([ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10]), array([21, 22, 23, 24, 25])]]
```

**Update** You can use [filter `numpy` by indices](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19821466/1283715)

```
J = [[1, 4]]
B = A[J[0]]
print([B])
```

O/P will be:

```
[array([[ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10],
       [21, 22, 23, 24, 25]])]
```

Comment: see the desired output..!

Comment: @YashMehta Check my update about using filter numpy array by indices, You are welcome!