# Index a numpy array with another array with tuples

Tags: python, numpy

I have read [Index a numpy array with another array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34082939/index-a-numpy-array-with-another-array)

I have two arrays `indices` and `image`

```
>>> indices.shape
(1031532, 3)
>>> image.shape
(589, 461, 361)
>>> indices[0:4,:]
array([[588, 153,  24],
       [588, 154, 340],
       [588, 156, 214],
       [588, 157, 277]], dtype=int32)
```

I want to set `image` to a certain value (say 255) for all indices contained in `indices`

I am new to python and I tried this:

```
image=np.zeros((indices[:,0].max()+1,indices[:,1].max()+1,indices[:,2].max()+1),dtype='uint8')
image[indices]=255 # understood that from the link above.
```

From reading , [Index a numpy array with another array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34082939/index-a-numpy-array-with-another-array), I tried

Looks like I can index it with an array element by element

```
>>> t=tuple(indices)
>>> image[tuple(t[0])]
```

but this (doing it all at once without a for loop) fails:

```
>>> image[tuple(indices)]=255
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: too many indices for array
```

I am expecting that all elements of image will be zero except for those listed in matrix `indices`.

So `image[588, 153,  24]=255` for example.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `image[ indices[:,0], indices[:,1], indices[:,2] ]`. `indices` is (n,3) shape.  `tuple(indices.T)` woukd be a tuple of 3 arrays.  So `image[tuple(indices.T)]` will be the same.

Comment: In particular, this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62370504/6275103

Comment: Basically for you, `image[tuple(indices.T)]`.

Comment: @DjaouadNM, thanks very much. That link and the command helped.